# Mongoose: using the pass option 'useUnifiedTopology: true' causing error handling to fail

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, npm, mongoose

I just noticed that if you use the 'useUnifiedTopology: true' option, mongoose will no longer emit an error if there's something wrong with the connection. For example:

```
mongoose.connect(DB, {
  useNewUrlParser: true,
  useCreateIndex: true,
  useFindAndModify: false,
  useUnifiedTopology: true
}).then((con) => {
  console.log("Connection successfully");
}).catch(err => console.log('Error'));
```

If the connection is successful, then the console will log 'Connection successfully'. But if there's something wrong (ex: wrong username or password) then nothing will happen.

Answer (score 1):

Generally you need to perform an operation to receive an error. Simply creating a client is insufficient as the client connects to the deployment in the background. Try sending `{ping:1}` or `{ismaster:1}`.

The rationale for this is described [here](https://github.com/mongodb/specifications/blob/master/source/server-discovery-and-monitoring/server-discovery-and-monitoring.rst#clients-do-no-i-o-in-the-constructor).

Comment: It is true that if you perform any operation after, then an error will be throw. But before that, I was able to catch the error during the client creation phase, and it fact I still can if I remove the 'useUnifiedTopology: true' option. I don't really understand what this option does and since it's a relatively new option, it is not very well documented.

Comment: Updated the answer with link to reasons. useUnifiedTopology option makes the node driver conform to the current philosophy that MongoDB drivers are meant to embody, as referenced.

Comment: I'm reading the document and to be honest I couldn't understand most of it since I'm still quite a newbie. But I don't think the problem has anything to deal with the document. So apparently, without 'useUnifiedTopology: true' option, then mongoose with throw an error immediately if there's something wrong with the connection to MongoDB, but with the option, it will take a while (around 30s for me) before throwing the connection error. So basically it still works, all you have to do is wait which I was too impatient and thought there was something wrong.

Comment: Both the old behavior and the new behavior (i.e. without/with unified topology option) are valid ways for a driver to behave in principle. The decision was made for the driver to behave in the new way. The new behavior is not a bug, and is not user-changeable to old behavior. The old behavior will at some point be completely removed from the driver.

Comment: You are correct that the new behavior provides delayed diagnostics. The way you are supposed to deal with this is by lowering the server selection timeout, which is described in https://docs.mongodb.com/ruby-driver/master/tutorials/ruby-driver-create-client/#development-configuration for the Ruby driver.  Node should be similar I imagine.